# Determine programmatically if an AIR app was launched from the command line?

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

Is it possible to determine programmatically whether an AIR app was launched from the command line or via double-click on the application icon?

I want to be able to do something like:

```
`if (e.launchedFromCLI) { foo(); }`
```

Answer (score 3):

Try listening to `NativeApplication` `INVOKE` event, it is the only place I know where you can find such info.

Seems that you can not distinguish CMD launch from icon launch - unless you pass some arguments in CMD.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/jslr/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#event:invoke

Comment: I'm already listening to INVOKE and parsing out arguments. The problem is, if I run the app by double-clicking an associated file, I get one argument (the file's path), if I run from the command line, I accept multiple arguments. I can invent some scheme, like starting all my command line arguments with a '-' character, and assuming if I get one argument *not* starting with a '-' it has come from a non-CLI launch, but this feels a bit of a hack.

Comment: @Jamie Bullock "The problem is, if I run the app by double-clicking an associated file, I get one argument (the file's path), if I run from the command line, I accept multiple arguments."  I'm not understanding what problem this introduces into your app.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com It's a problem when I get *exactly one* argument. In this case the only way to determine what the argument represents is to examine its contents and employ some heuristics like if (args[0].substr( 0, 1 ) != "-") {}. It would be better if Flex provided a way to programmatically determine whether a given argument represents a path passed from icon launch.

Comment: I don't know if AIR knows why an application was launched. If the OS starts the execution with a file name on the command-line, how would AIR know that the user did not start it (through the OS) with a file name on the command-line.

Loosely-coupled modules have a lot of benefits, but it means that they don't know a lot about each other.